# How to get a handle to workbook / worksheet for activated / opened OLE object?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet that has dozens of embedded Excel objects. My goal is to save each of the Ole objects as its own separate spreadsheet file.

I find all OLEObjects in a Worksheet and I activate each one:

```
For Each oleObject In sheet.OLEObjects
        oleObject.Activate
```

The activate causes a new Workbook to be created. How do I get a handle to this newly created Workbook so I can save it and close it before the next workbook is created? Activate method returns a Variant but I need a Workbook instead.

Is there another way to accomplish my goal?

Thanks,
Eddie

Comment: Maybe “Dim wb As Workbook” followed by “Set wb = ActiveWorkbook” right after the code line that creates the new workbook

Comment: Thank you. But it looks like the ActiveWorkbook is the workbook from where I grabbed the OLEObjects - not the newly created workbook from the OLEObject.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to activate the oleobject - usually activation is not needed.

Try looking at oleObject.Parent 
This would usually be a worksheet object.

If so then oleIbject.Parent.Parent will return the parent workbook object.